# How to take an input from a text box and change text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get an input from a text input box to transform a paragraph into what's in the input box. Note that this is not a web page just code run in a Browser.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form><center>
First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Firstname" id="JohnnyFunc"></form>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction">Submit</button>
<script>
  function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("JhonnyOutput"). innerHTML="JohnnyFunc"
}
</script>
<center><p>Hello</p><p id="JhonnyOutput">Johhny!</p></center>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The onclick attribute should include the parentheses after the function name: `onclick="myFunction()"`

```
<form>
    <center>First name:<br><input type="text" name="Firstname" id="JohnnyFunc"></center>
</form>
<center><button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button></center>
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        document.getElementById("JhonnyOutput"). innerHTML="JohnnyFunc"
    }
</script>
<center><p>Hello</p><p id="JhonnyOutput">Johhny!</p></center>
```

You were also missing a closing tag for your first `<center>` element

Also, to change the text to what's in the text box, you need to get the text from the input element:

```
function myFunction() {
    var newText = document.getElementById("JohnnyFunc").value
    document.getElementById("JhonnyOutput").innerHTML = newText
}
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong here because i added the all that you did and it does not work. When i press the Submit button the text changes from "Johnny!" to "JohnnyFunc". Why? I'm not very experienced with coding so yeah.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make it clear that you need to substitute the second block of code in for `myFunction()` in order to get the text from the textbox into the paragraph. Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ou0tLyx4/1/) to demonstrate